# How do I fill a Table using JFormDesigner

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jform-designer

I'm new to JFormDesigner and can't seem to understand how to fill a generated JTable using the model that was generated by JFormDesigner. I'm thinking of trashing JFoemDesigner and just using basic Swing.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: *I'm thinking of trashing JFoemDesigner and just using basic Swing.* - that would be my suggestion. If you learn the form design the knowledge will not be portable if you move to another IDE. By learning Swing you will be able top work in any environment and you are in full control of the code. The IDE is helpful for compiling and debugging but don't let it generate your code.

Comment: The Oracle tutorial [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) is pretty good.  Skip the NetBeans section.

Comment: Thanks, I already know how to create a Swing GUI, I'm just attempting to see if a JFormDesigner would reduce the time to develop.